# Dealing with an invalid operands error

Tags: c++, operands

I've been tasked with fixing a sample code full of errors for a C++ programming class. This program is designed so that two numbers are entered as the input -- the first number subsequently divided by the second -- and the output is the remainder. I've worked off almost all of the errors, but I'm having an issue with one remaining error (that I can gather), which I can't seem to figure out.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int firstNumber; 
    double secondNumber;

    cout << "Please enter two whole numbers: ";
    cin >> firstNumber >> secondNumber;
    cout << firstNumber << " divided by " << secondNumber
         << " is " << (firstNumber / secondNumber) << endl
         << "with a remainder of " << (firstNumber % secondNumber) 
         << endl;
}
```

The error I'm getting is in Line 13 ... "invalid operands of types 'int' and 'double' to binary 'operator%.'

Any advice on how to work through this issue...?

Comment: In C++, `%` only works with integers.

Comment: In using google search as a tool to help give me some possible suggestions. I tried switching out fmod() with % as a result, but couldn't get that to work either. Although, admittedly, I only toyed around with that for a bit. Is fmod() more on the right path of what I need to use to fix this program?

Comment: Yes, doing `std::fmod(firstNumber, secondNumber)` will work.

Comment: @JustinWells That depends on what you want it to do. Normally, modulus is an integer operation, as is division with a remainder.

Comment: @molbdnilo -- Sorry, should have been clearer. I edited my original post to reflect that ... the program is designed to find a remainder. Two numbers are entered as the input -- first number divided by second -- output is the remainder.

Comment: @JaydoubleU Is it essential to your program that one number is an integer and the other is a floating point number? Use `int`for both otherwise.

Comment: @0x499602D2 -- Tried that, didn't work. Resulting error was "'fmod is not a member of 'std.'"

Comment: You need to include the header `<cmath>`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 -- I'm using Dev C++ ... and either it doesn't recognize or doesn't support `<cmath>`. I tried using `<math.h>` ... and had the same error message "'fmod is not a member of 'std.'"

Comment: Then just remove the `std::` part (and get a better compiler).

Comment: Hah ... do you have any recommendations on compilers?

Comment: [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html) or [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/).

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people are talking about how the mod operator (%) in C++ only works on integers. Some have suggested casting  `secondNumber` to an int and others have mentioned mod operations that work on floating point numbers like `fmod`.

A better solution to this problem would be to declare `secondNumber` as an integer at the beginning of the program. When dealing with integer division (quotient remainder) there is no reason to use floating point numbers. Your problem definition seems only to be defined for integers so we should be using only integers.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int firstNumber, secondNumber;

    cout << "Please enter two whole numbers: ";
    cin >> firstNumber >> secondNumber;
    cout << firstNumber << " divided by " << secondNumber
         << " is " << (firstNumber / secondNumber) << endl
         << "with a remainder of " << (firstNumber % secondNumber) 
         << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is surely the intended solution

Comment: @0xDE1337 ... that did the trick. I was wondering if the declaration of the firstNumber and secondNumber had an impact on the program. But I definitely didn't come up with what you did. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`(firstNumber % secondNumber)` is causing your error since `%` only works with integer types.  If you need to you can either cast `secondNumber` to and int like:

```
(firstNumber % static_cast<int>(secondNumber))
```

Or you can use the [fmod()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/fmod/) function

Comment: I tried to cast `secondNumber` to an int, and the program wouldn't compile. Perhaps this could be because the operand `double` is connected to `secondNumber` at the beginning of the program...?